# For a matrix of continous function, does the identity $ \det(e^{A(x)}) = e^{\text{trace}(A(x))} $ still holds?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-exponential

Assuming that every entry of in the matrix is a continuous function and the matrix is invertible. Would it still be true that $ \det(e^{A(x)}) = e^{\text{trace}(A(x))}  $? Would appreciate if somebody could just throw me a yes or no answer. Thank you!

Comment: A matrix is a matrix no matter if it's elements are functions. Just take the Jacobian for example.

Comment: Hence the identity would still hold? It's just that the definition for the matrix exponential involves the convergence of series which makes me doubts the validity of the claim.

Comment: The power series expansion for the exponential is convergent everywhere for $\mathbb R,\mathbb C$ because it has no poles.

Comment: I see now, thank you!

Comment: yes it will work, trace is the sum of eigenvalues, det is product, exp acts on eigenvalues as if they were scalars. the rest you can deduce from the exp and log laws.

Comment: Yes, it works, since you just apply the usual “constant” identity for each fixed $x$ separately.